# Write data ower Modbus tcp to HUAWEI SUN2000 KTL error

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, huawei-iap

I would like to change the PV inverter settings via **Modbus TCP**.

the system reads correctly when I write I get an error!!!

I use Raspberry PI and Python.

Modbus address is **40125** and data is **RW** (readable and writable, U16 unsigned integer (16 bits))

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient


client = ModbusClient('192.168.1.116', port=502)

client.connect()


if client.connect():


    APPD = client.read_holding_registers(40125, 1, 1)
    print (APPD.registers[0])


    replay = client.write_registers(40125,500,1)
    
    print(replay)
```

Read: 10000

Write: Exception Response(144, 16, IllegalAddress)

What could be wrong?

Comment: The leading numeral (4) in the register address probably denotes `holding register`. Since you already use the function `read_holding_registers` you must skip this and use register `125` instead.

Comment: I tried skip `read` and `replay = client.write_registers(125,10,1)` and gave an answer `Exception Response(134, 6, IllegalAddress)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean skip reading but skip the (4). So to read `read_holding_registers(125,1,1)`. To write try function code 0x6, so  `write_register(125,10,1)`.

Comment: I tried `replay = client.write_registers(125,10,1)` same answer `Exception Response(134, 6, IllegalAddress)`

Comment: The plural `write_registers` is not the same as `write_register`.

Comment: I tried both, still showing the same error.

Comment: Can you read any other register?

Comment: Reads correctly, I tried write other addresses, still the same. Inverter manulal [PDF](https://javierin.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/09/Solar-Inverter-Modbus-Interface-Definitions.pdf) I usage Modbus Poll software the same error to write.

Comment: The manual says the default address of the slave node is 0. Are you sure you are using the correct slave id?

Comment: The reading works correctly PV1 V. - `32016` = 666, PV2 V.  - `32018` = 544, Grid Hz - `32085` = 50,01 ... I also checked the device slave id is `1`. I have always read, but this time I need to write to the address :(

Comment: @Maario can you post the actual command that you are sending? It's easy to check via Modbus Poll.

Comment: Are you using a Huawei WLAN-FE Smart Dongle?

Comment: Inverter is `SUN2000-10KTL-M1` (V100R001C00SPC153) and `WLAN-FE` (V100R001C00SPC125) over LAN cable (not using wifi) READ `40125` Tx:`01 1F 00 00 00 06 01 03 9C BD 00 01`   Rx:`01 1F 00 00 00 05 01 03 02 03 E8`   
WRITE `40125` VALUE - `100`   Tx:`01 20 00 00 00 06 01 06 9C BD 00 64`    Rx:`01 20 00 00 00 03 01 86 02`

Comment: @Maario everything looks okay; try reading from and writing to 40124 and 40126 and seeing what happens? You should get a 0x02 on reading 40124. Can you write to any R/W registers? If you have equipment currently in use, try to change the time-zone  - write to 43006. Addresses can be weird in Modbus, so while you are getting a read from 40125, I would like to have you verify that you indeed can write (I checked if there are any passwords you are supposed to set before writing - some systems do that - but I don't see any) and that your addressing scheme is correct. If not - contact the mfg.

Comment: Note that you are [not the only user](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/integration-solar-inverter-huawei-2000l/132350/2499) to encounter this kind of issue with the dongle.

Comment: I can read all the values correctly. It's weird I tried to write some value `40000` - `42999` same error except for Reactive power adjustment time - `40124` i can write! and  `43000` + and higher value I can write correctly!!! Funny (`43006` Tx:`00 02 00 00 00 06 01 06 A7 FE 00 82` Rx:`00 02 00 00 00 06 01 06 A7 FE 00 82`)

Comment: @Maario that tells me something is off - register 40124 isn't defined in the manual that you have linked. Which register are you specifically talking about? What do you mean you have tried to write some value 40000 - 42999? Because you can't write more than effectively ~ 127 registers at a time.

Comment: I scanned the addresses with the ModBus Pool and I tried to change some that were of value. I tested 40124 which values ​​change in the device's software and ModBus reads. I think that the inverter itself does not allow writing.

Comment: @Maario I'm not sure which software you are using exactly, so at this point I'd direct you to Huawei forums, they provide support there as well.